# Trouble implementing java hangman to return blanks with correct letters (e.g. "_ _ r _")

Tags: java, bluej

I've been working on a text-based hangman game in Java BlueJ for a school project and have been mostly successful, but I ran into a bit of a wall with this part.

I'm trying to make it so every time the player guesses a letter correctly, it prints out the blank spaces (asterisks) with the correct letters inserted. Right now, I have it printing out the letter you guessed and past correct guesses with the correct number of blanks. **My only issue now is that it prints an incorrect number of blanks at the start of the game.**

How can I fix this issue with the blank spaces?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman {
    Word w = new Word();
    private String word = w.chooseWord();
    private int count = 0;
    String guess;

public String getWord() {
    String w = word;
    return w;
}

public int countLetters() {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(i))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public String Blanks() {
    countLetters();
    int num = 0;
    String spaces = "";
    String blankSpace = "*";
    while (num < count) {
        spaces = spaces + blankSpace;
        num++;
    }
    return spaces;
}

String wordSoFar = Blanks();

public int countOccurrences() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.substring(i, i + 1).equals(guess)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public String wordSoFar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.substring(i, i + 1).equals(guess)) {
            wordSoFar = wordSoFar.substring(0, i) + guess + wordSoFar.substring(i + 1 , wordSoFar.length());
        }
    }
    return wordSoFar;
}  

public void Guess() {
    //Removed code that draws hangman due to it making this really long

    boolean correct = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numIncorrectGuesses = 0;
    int numCorrectGuesses = 0;

    while (numCorrectGuesses != word.length() && numIncorrectGuesses < 6) {  
        guess = scan.next().substring(0,1);

        if (word.contains(guess)) {
            correct = true;
            numCorrectGuesses += countOccurrences();
            System.out.println(wordSoFar());
        } else {
            correct = false;
            numIncorrectGuesses++;
        }

    //Removed code that draws hangman due to it making this really long

    if (numCorrectGuesses == word.length()) {
        System.out.println("You win");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You lose");
    }
}
```

Adding driver class:

```
public class runGame {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Hangman game = new Hangman();
        System.out.println(game.getWord());
        System.out.println(game.Blanks());
        game.Guess();
    }
}
```

Class that selects word:

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Word {
        //String[] bank = {removing word bank due to length};

        public String chooseWord() {
            Random r = new Random();
            return new String(bank[r.nextInt(bank.length)]);
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of the craziness that happens (the first line is just for testing; final game won't show the word. The single character lines are my guesses):

```
object
************
    _______
   |/      |
   |
   |
   |
   |
   |
___|___
o
o*****
b
ob****
j
obj***
e
obje**
c
objec*
t
object
You win
```

Comment: Please see I have edited your question to include an actual question at the end of the introduction. Specifics are good :)

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time posting on this site and I'm just learning how to do it!

Comment: Hi, just a suggestion. Maybe you should remove the part where you draw your 'hangman' when posting a question. It is making the question relatively long and hard to read!

Comment: @Gosu So many times, left out code is the cause of the issue, best to include all full relevant code don't you think?

Comment: @Ross it might be due to how BlueJ works. The main function might be hidden and executed on the student's behalf. If you make a main function, create a Hangman object, and run hangman.Guess(), it works.

Comment: @Ross I don't think all the `System.out.println` for printing out the hangman would be the issue in this case! I guess it would be better to keep the code as minimal as possible!

Comment: @goodpeopleatoracle you are only storing the last guess in the 'guess' variable but not storing the history. With each successive input from the user, guess is lost. All of your logic is based upon that guess variable. There are a few ways to solve this problem. One way is to store all the guesses into a list and iterate through all the previous guesses to build the final output string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to remove the line

```
wordSoFar = Blanks();
```

from the beginning of wordSoFar() function. Instead do it at the beginning of guess() function. You are initializing it with blank every time you guess a new character. And every time you call Blank() function, it increase count (as it is a class variable), which eventually increases number of "_".

Now for your current double * problem, write a getter for wordSoFar in Hangman class.

```
public String getWordSoFar() {
    return wordSoFar
}
```

And in main function

```
public class runGame {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Hangman game = new Hangman();
        System.out.println(game.getWord());
        System.out.println(game.getWordSoFar());
        game.Guess();
    }
}
```

And another think, countLetter() function should initialize the count to 0 before counting.

```
public int countLetters() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(word.charAt(i))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: When I move that line into the beginning of guess(), it prints the correct number of blanks at the beginning of the game but for each correct guess, prints double the correct number of blanks (but the guessed letters show up fine). Alternatively, if I put that line immediately after the Blanks() method (like I have it up in my question), it does the opposite. Tons of blanks at first, correct number when you start guessing

Comment: Look at your count variable that is used in your Blanks(); function. Now your wordSoFar is class variable, so it call Blanks() when your class initializes, that is when Hangman game = new Hangman(); in main function. You again called Blanks() when you print using System.out.println(game.Blanks());, it increase your count and "*". You should print wordSoFar instead of calling game.Blanks() like System.out.println(game.wordSoFar); in your main function. You may add a getter for wordSoFar and write like  System.out.println(game.getWordSoFar()).

Comment: All of it worked out properly. The fact that I called game.Blanks() was precisely the reason it printed double, it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a String, you could can convert it to a array of chars

```
char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
char[] blankArray = new char[wordArray.length];
Arrays.fill(blankArray,'_');
```

Guess should be a character since the user should only be able to guess one letter

Then for this

```
public String wordSoFar(){
    for(int i = 0; i < wordArray.length(); i++){
        if(wordArray[i] == guess){
            blankArray[i] = wordArray[i];
        }
    }
    return blankArray;
}
```

The blankArray keeps on getting pieced together. You can test if its solved by

```
if(String(blankArray)==String(wordArray)){}
```

Comment: I don't think a char array is very unicode friendly

Comment: It gives me the message: "<identifier> expected" and highlights the line "Array.fill(blankArray,'_');"   Am I just putting it in the wrong place (right after my instance variables)?

Comment: You could just use a for loop to fill it with blanks